# What is binding of methods?

Tags: java, programming-languages

For my class, comparative languages, there is an example exam and one of the quesitons is: "What is binding of methods?"

So, what is it?

The question goes on to ask what is static versus dynamic binding which, the difference here is compile time versus run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to the process that takes a method name and parameter types (eg, `toString()`) and finds the actual method that should be called (finding the right method from the appropriate type or base type and performing overload resolution).

Comment: In theory, it can consider the return type in the binding it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Use google for these kinds of questions.

http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html